# Handling nested optional data in cypher Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am writing a cypher which handles optional data called `questions`. The idea behind it is to create a relationship such as shown:

```
(dot:Dot)<-[:IS_ABOUT]-(q:Question)<-[:IS_ABOUT]-(a:Answer)
```

The data that is being passed in as questions, which is an array which contains text, answers and optional guid values. This questions parameter could also be an empty array, and also as new data is being added to the questions array they won't contain or have a guid.

The issue is when I run the query it fails to execute and run, I have had no luck with `UNWIND`  either, any help would be greatly appreciated!

If the question and answer contain a guid then it should match and update the values but if the question and answer contain no guid then it should create new nodes.

```
WITH [
  {
    text: "something",
    guid: "9a4aeac0-4ea4-469a-80c1-908573a4ad55",
    answer: [
      {
        text: "something",
        guid: "9a4aeac0-4ea4-469a-80c1-908573a74635",
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: "something",
        guid: "9a4aeac0-4ea4-469a-80c1-908573a4ad22",
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: "something",
        guid: "9a4aeac0-4ea4-469a-80c1-908573a4a987",
        correct: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: "something",
    answer: [
      {
        text: "something",
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: "something",
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: "something",
        correct: false
      }
    ]
  }
] as questions

MATCH (d:Dot{GUID: "9a4aeac0-4ea4-469a-80c1-908573a4ad61"})

WITH d, questions

FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN questions IS NOT NULL THEN [1]
  ELSE []
  END |
  FOREACH (question IN questions |
    MERGE (q:Trivia:Question { GUID: question.guid })
      ON CREATE SET q.GUID = apoc.create.uuid(), q.creationDate = datetime(), q.text = question.text
      ON MATCH SET q.text = question.text
    MERGE (q)-[g:IS_ABOUT]->(dot)
      ON CREATE SET g.creationDate = datetime()
    FOREACH (answer IN question.answer |
      MERGE (a:Trivia:Answer { GUID: answer.guid })
        ON CREATE SET a.GUID = apoc.create.uuid(), a.creationDate = datetime(), a.text = answer.text, a.
          correct = answer.correct
        ON MATCH SET  a.text = answer.text, a.correct = answer.correct
      MERGE (a)-[t:TO]->(q)
        ON CREATE SET t.creationDate = datetime()
    )
  )
)

RETURN d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATED]

The second element in your `questions` list is missing all the `guid` properties expected by your Cypher code.

Here is a fixed example (that provides all the expected `guid` properties):

```
WITH [
  {
    text: "something",
    guid: "9a4aeac0-4ea4-469a-80c1-908573a4ad55",
    answer: [
      {
        text: "something",
        guid: "9a4aeac0-4ea4-469a-80c1-908573a74635",
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: "something",
        guid: "9a4aeac0-4ea4-469a-80c1-908573a4ad22",
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: "something",
        guid: "9a4aeac0-4ea4-469a-80c1-908573a4a987",
        correct: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: "something",
    guid: "9a4aeac0-4ea4-469a-80c1-908573a4ad66",
    answer: [
      {
        text: "something",
        guid: "9a4aeac0-4ea4-469a-80c1-908573a74611",
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: "something",
        guid: "9a4aeac0-4ea4-469a-80c1-908573a74622",
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: "something",
        guid: "9a4aeac0-4ea4-469a-80c1-908573a74633",
        correct: false
      }
    ]
  }
] as questions

MATCH (dot:Dot{GUID: "9a4aeac0-4ea4-469a-80c1-908573a4ad61"})

FOREACH (question IN questions |
  MERGE (q:Trivia:Question { GUID: question.guid })
    ON CREATE SET q.GUID = apoc.create.uuid(), q.creationDate = datetime(), q.text = question.text
    ON MATCH SET q.text = question.text
  MERGE (q)-[g:IS_ABOUT]->(dot)
    ON CREATE SET g.creationDate = datetime()
  FOREACH (answer IN question.answer |
    MERGE (a:Trivia:Answer { GUID: answer.guid })
      ON CREATE SET a.GUID = apoc.create.uuid(), a.creationDate = datetime(), a.text = answer.text, a.correct = answer.correct
      ON MATCH SET  a.text = answer.text, a.correct = answer.correct
    MERGE (a)-[t:TO]->(q)
      ON CREATE SET t.creationDate = datetime()
  )
)

RETURN dot
```

Comment: Hi Cybersam, thanks for responding! I am still having the same error when running the cypher with the relationships not being created on the Dot node.

Comment: I updated my answer to fix a typo (that also existed in your query). `d` should have been `dot`.